# Matrix multiplication in cuSparse (cusparseDcsrgemm) outputs wrong results

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to compute `A^TA` using cuSparse. A is a large but sparse matrix. The problem is when I use the function `cusparseDcsrgemm`, the computed output is wrong. Please see the below minimal example to reproduce the problem.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(sample)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_14)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PUBLIC ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

int main(){
  // 3x3 identity matrix in CSR format
  std::vector<int> row;
  std::vector<int> col;
  std::vector<double> val;

  row.emplace_back(0);
  row.emplace_back(1);
  row.emplace_back(2);
  row.emplace_back(3);

  col.emplace_back(0);
  col.emplace_back(1);
  col.emplace_back(2);

  val.emplace_back(1);
  val.emplace_back(1);
  val.emplace_back(1);

  int *d_row;
  int *d_col;
  double *d_val;

  int *d_out_row;
  int *d_out_col;
  double *d_out_val;

  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_row), row.size() * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_col), col.size() * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_val), val.size() * sizeof(double));

  // we know identity transpose times identity is still identity 
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_out_row), row.size() * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_out_col), col.size() * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&d_out_val), val.size() * sizeof(double));

  cudaMemcpy(
      d_row, row.data(), sizeof(int) * row.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(
      d_col, col.data(), sizeof(int) * col.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(
      d_val, val.data(), sizeof(double) * val.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  cusparseHandle_t handle;
  cusparseCreate(&handle);

  cusparseMatDescr_t descr;
  cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descr);
  cusparseSetMatType(descr, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
  cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

  cusparseMatDescr_t descr_out;
  cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descr_out);
  cusparseSetMatType(descr_out, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
  cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descr_out, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

  cusparseDcsrgemm(handle,
                   CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE,
                   CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE,
                   3,
                   3,
                   3,
                   descr,
                   3,
                   d_val,
                   d_row,
                   d_col,
                   descr,
                   3,
                   d_val,
                   d_row,
                   d_col,
                   descr_out,
                   d_out_val,
                   d_out_row,
                   d_out_col);

  cudaMemcpy(
      row.data(), d_out_row, sizeof(int) * row.size(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(
      col.data(), d_out_col, sizeof(int) * col.size(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(
      val.data(), d_out_val, sizeof(double) * val.size(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  std::cout << "row" << std::endl;
  for (int i : row)
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //show 0 0 0 0, but it should be 0 1 2 3
  }

  std::cout << "col" << std::endl;
  for (int i : col)
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //show 1 0 0, but it should be 0 1 2
  }

  std::cout << "val" << std::endl;
  for (int i : val)
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl; //show 1 0 0, but it should be 1 1 1
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Shadow in this toy scenario the total number of nonzero elements for the output matrix is known, so `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz` is not needed. I also tried `cusparseDcsrgemm2` and it's the same problem. I tried to keep the minimal example as minimal as possible.

Comment: @Shadow I think I see the problem now... `d_out_row` is actually an input to `cusparseDcsrgemm` instead of an output. For none toy scenarios `d_out_row` is calculated by `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz`.  Thanks and if you write out an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot one step because you tried to make an easy example.
In the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#csrgemm) it is stated:

> The cuSPARSE library adopts a two-step approach to complete sparse matrix. In the first step, the user allocates `csrRowPtrC` of `m+1` elements and uses the function `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz()` to determine `csrRowPtrC` and the total number of nonzero elements.

What you did is to allocate `m+1`(`m=3` in your example) elements for `d_row_out` and you determined the total number of nonzero elements which is `3` in your example.
But you missed do "determine `d_row_out`" which means to fill the vector with the right values.
In your simple example you could just add the line

```
cudaMemcpy(d_out_row, row.data(), sizeof(int) * row.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

somewhere before your gemm call.

The more general approach of course would be to use the suggested function `cusparseXcsrgemmNnz()`.
You could add the following lines somewhere before your gemm call (many values are still hardcoded as in your example, so it's not really general):

```
int nnz_check[1];
cusparseXcsrgemmNnz(handle,
                    CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE,
                    CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE,
                    3,
                    3,
                    3,
                    descr,
                    3,
                    d_row,
                    d_col,
                    descr,
                    3,
                    d_row,
                    d_col,
                    descr_out,
                    d_out_row,  // the values this pointer points to will be set
                    nnz_check); // the number of nonzeros will also be calculated
assert(nnz_check[0] == 3);
```

---

Side note: The documentation says "[[DEPRECATED]] use `cusparse<t>csrgemm2()` instead. The routine will be removed in the next major release", that is version 11.
The problem still remains for the second gemm version though as the same two-step approach is used.

Comment: I think you meant `cudaMemcpy(d_out_row, row.data(), sizeof(int) * row.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`